# C# - Automatically generating keys in a SortedList

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I would like to create a SortedList with just keys of type Integer, but I'm finding it difficult to set them myself considering the nature of the code.

Is there any way for the list to generate the keys themselves? Like, an autonumber sort of thing? This may be obvious but I've been Googling away and can't find anything!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a standard `List<T>`? They are sorted by an index, which is always incremented.

Comment: I need to access all Keys and enumerate around them - could you do that with a List<T>?

Comment: The definition for my SortedList is SortedList<int, KeyValuePair<int, Cell>>(). I need to find the minimum Key as well as search using Linq within the Keys, so I'm not sure I could do that with a standard List<T>...

Comment: @NewStart I suggest using a `List` and seeing if there are any problems for you, rather than theorizing about whether or not it will work.  I find it rather likely that it will be fine.  If you have problems doing some particular task, feel free to post it as a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap SortedList around with a class defined by you, that could do the extra book keeping.

Answer (score 0):

An autonumber (or IDENTITY) is really just a thread-safe counter, so you could just create a property or class level variable that retrieves the next value and then increments that value:

```
class TestAutoIncrement
    {
        int counter = 0;
        private Object thisLock = new Object();

        public int GetNextCounterValue()
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                counter++;
                return counter;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Interlock.Increment` might be easier.

Comment: changing the `GetNextCounterValue` and  `counter` to static properties will be more efficient

Comment: @TheSimon That assumes counters need to be unique across multiple instances of the data structure, which is likely not the case.

Comment: @DanielA.White I was unfamiliar with that. Thanks!